# Determine divergence of integral using comparison test of $e^{x^2}/x^2$

Tags: calculus, limits, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I'm usually good at determining divergence and using the comparison test, but I can't figure out what function I can use to determine if 
$$ \int_{0}^{1} \frac{e^{x^2}}{x^2} \, dx$$
is divergent. If anyone can help me, that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/

Answer (score 2):

$$x^2\ge 0\implies e^{x^2}\ge 1\implies \int^1_0\frac{e^{x^2}}{x^2}dx\ge\int^1_0\frac1{x^2}dx=\infty$$

Thus the integral is divergent.

Comment: I can see how 1/x^2 can be less than, but when are they ever equal?

Comment: @A.B. They aren’t equal anywhere.

Comment: Doesn't comparison rule require it to be equal? and when you wrote that the first intergal is greater than or equal to the second, isn't that where you said they can be equal?

Comment: @A.B. No matter greater than or equal, the integral is lower bounded by positive infinity, so...

Answer (score 1):

Using the Taylor series:
$$\begin{align}\int_{0}^{1} \frac{e^{x^2}}{x^2} \, dx&=\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1+x^2+\frac{x^4}{2!}+O(x^6)}{x^2} \, dx=\\
&=\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{x^2}+1+\frac{x^2}{2!}+O(x^4) \, dx>\\
&>\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{x^2} \, dx=\\
&=\lim_{x\to 1^-}\left(-\frac1x\right)-\lim_{x\to 0^+}\left(-\frac1x\right)=\\
&=-1+\infty=+\infty. \end{align}$$
Thus, the integral diverges.

Answer (score 0):

For $x>0$, $e^{x^2}>1$ then
$$\dfrac{e^{x^2}}{x^2}>\dfrac{1}{x^2}$$